# What is the difference between the "formality" and "formal" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags that seem related: [formality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formality), and [formal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal).

The first is described as the tag to use for questions about formality of words or sentences. The other tag doesn't have any description, but I would imagine it means the OP wants a formal word, not that the OP is asking about how formal is a word.

Did I understand how to use [formal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal) correctly?

Comment: "Formality" is a question asking *how formal is X versus Y*, whereas "Formal" says *I want you to answer the question bearing in mind that I intend to use the result in formal text*. Whether they are good tags is a different question - but they are at least different.